Why is the length of a Faraday cage's lattice relevant to what wavelengths it blocks?
I believe the title is self-explanatory. I see a similar reasoning pop up often in other areas where EM radiation is being manipulated, e.g. lasers, radars, radio telescopes and so on.
The wavelength of the incoming radiation has an inverse relationship with its frequency and the frequency determines the energy level of the photos and how those may interact with electrons in whatever material comes in their way.
Now I guess the lattice geometry may have some effect on how the radiation is dispersed or scattered, e.g. the cage is magnetized and creates new magnetic fields and you'll write some complex integrals and find out that things will cancel out in a certain direction based on the lattice's physical properties. That makes sense to me but I still I don't understand why a wave cycle "fitting" into a hole has any relevance as the wave doesn't have a physical size. I find this analogy confusing and misleading.
I'd appreciate if you could clear this up for me.

Who says the wave doesn't have a physical size?  By that token, evanescent waves wouldn't happen either.

The wave is made of two oscillating fields and the effects of each field is present in the entirety of their corresponding planes. I don't know how you can associate a size with it. Also the waves are transverse, so the wavelength is perpendicular to the surface of the hole (think of the hole as a circle on a plane) not tangent, so fitting through a hole doesn't make sense.

Clearly then the length of an antenna should have no effect on how well it radiates?

Can we shine light through a hole into a metal can? Yes. Why? Because the wavelength is much shorter than the size of the hole, i.e. the electromagnetic field does not have any matter to interact with in the center of the hole. Near the edges there will be diffraction effects. If the size of the hole is similar to the wavelength, then most of the field will be diffracted, but there will still be plenty of electromagnetic wave energy penetrating the can. Only if the wavelength is much longer than the size of the opening will most of the wave be reflected. See Rayleigh scattering for details.

@JonCuster Well I don't understand the antenna either.. The way I see it, it should oscillate with the frequency of the incoming radiation regardless of its own length.

@FlatterMann When you're shining the light (assuming at a 90 degree angle through the can), the only thing that the sides of the can will feel are period variations in intensity of EM fields (in fact anything inside the can will feel that). I don't see how the wavelength of the light has any role here.

Not only will the metal "feel" those variations, it will respond to them. That's why it's reflective. If you add the response to the original field (by solving Maxwell's equations) then you will see that for wavelengths much longer than the dimensions of the hole almost all radiation will be reflected. Rayleigh scattering theory simplifies this problem using a dipole model instead of a finite size hole, but nothing stops you from solving the equations numerically if you want realistic results for an arbitrary geometry.

@Paghillect, the reflected wave is the product not just of the wave impinging on one point on the reflective surface, but on how it reflects off all the different points on the surface. How those multiple (infinite) reflections recombine at some point away from the surface depends very much on the wavelength of the radiation.

Think of each hole in the Faraday cage as a very short waveguide. If the wavelength of the radiation is short enough (roughly $\lambda < 2d$ where $d$ is the diameter of the hole), then that radiation when it impinges on one side of the hole, can be coupled into a guided mode of the "waveguide", propagate through the hole, and be coupled again to a free-space mode on the other side of the hole.
Even if the wavelength is slightly larger than twice the diameter of the hole, it can couple to an evenascent mode of the "waveguide", and because the wavelength is not too much bigger than the hole, the characteristic decay length of the evanescent mode will be relatively long, allowing evanescent coupling from one side of the "waveguide" to the other.

The wavelength of the incoming radiation has an inverse relationship with its frequency and the frequency determines the energy level of the photos and how those may interact with electrons in whatever material comes in their way.

Considering the quantum (photon) behavior of the radiation is not helpful here. The operation of the Faraday cage can be analyzed from purely classical electromagnetics principles.

The waveguide is useful analogy and an entirely new concept to me. However, this still doesn't answer my question. The wavelength only tells us how long it's gonna take between each peak of the either of the EM field components but the effects of those fields are going to be present regardless of phase. Furthermore, assuming the wave hits the hole at a 90% angle, then the wavelength no longer "fits" in the diameter of the hole and the hole should become transparent to the wave.
Can you link to some diagrams or figures?

As a follow up, the way I understand the EM wave is not as a moving entity (like sound), but rather as the propagation of variations in the intensity of EM fields as sensed at a fixed point in space. That point is going to feel the EM field effects regardless of how far away the next peak is.

If your model for how the EM wave works doesn't predict actual experimental results, then you should probably try to improve your model. The mainstream physics model of waves in the EM field predicts that waves can't propagate through holes in conductive materials smaller than about half the wavelength, and this is verified by experiment. You haven't said enough about your model for us to know if it agrees or not with the conventional model.

It's not that I have a model (I'm not trying to rediscover physics), it's rather that based on my current understanding of existing physics, I don't understand why the wavelength should matter. There's a gap in my understanding and that's what I'm trying to understand.

@Paghillect, you have a mental model that tells you "the EM wave is not as a moving entity (like sound), but rather as the propagation of variations in the intensity of EM fields". Those words aren't clear enough to me to say why they're wrong. But if this mental model is telling you that the wavelength doesn't affect what size waveguide a signal can travel through then you need to improve this model.

FWIW, the conventional physics model of electromagnetic waves is that they do move through space in a very similar way to how sound waves move through a medium. So if your nental model says that electromagnetic waves don't move, that's another area to reconsider your mental model.

I think it boils down to me not understanding why we are associating a size with something that's field (and therefore has infinite reach, though it fades out to basically after a certain distance). When you picture a moving EM wave, it has peaks with wavelength of distance between them. I find that image useless if you're thinking about a single photon, since rather than existing everywhere along the direction of propagation at once (as the classical visualization would make you think), it exists with varying amplitudes at different points in space at different times as it propagates.

This way of thinking makes sense as you still get to associate a frequency with a single photon. Whereas in case of sound, frequency doesn't make sense with a single air molecule. You will only hear a sound after many many air molecules have hit your ears over a short span of time, so that you have enough sample points to derive a frequency. Continuing with this line of reasoning, I think it's clear why I fail to appreciate the significance of wavelength. For me, there's a disconnect between the concept of an air wave and that of an EM wave.

@Paghillect, the quantum "particle" associated with a sound wave is a phonon, not an air molecule.

What I mean is, you're absolutely right that we don't expect an EM wave to relate to a photon the way a sound wave relates to an air molecule...because they are absolutely not in an analogous relationship. If you want to find the thing that relates to a sound wave the way a photon relates to an EM wave, it's the phonon, not the air molecule.

What confused physics for some years (prior to 1905 or so) was, if you want to find the object that relates to an EM wave the same way an air molecule relates to the sound wave...you can't. There is no such object, except the electromagnetic field itself.

When you say a field "has infinite reach", that's only true when you don't put boundaries on the space the wave in the field can propagate through. Conductive surfaces constrain the space the EM wave can exist in. (If you're solving the EM wave equation as a differential equation, they establish boundary conditions on the equation) The "size" of the photon (of a given frequency) is essentially the smallest volume you can contain the photon in using such boundaries.
